# Any other better ways than this messy code to write php script that finds the minimum number that is divisible from 1 to 12

Tags: php

My idea was something like this for finding the minimum number that is divisible from 1 to 12.
The problem is, i have to use if condition all the way-long as the range of number increases.
Is there any better way than this messy code.Sorry am a beginner from level 0.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 999999; $i++) {
  $num = 12 * $i;

  if ($num % 12 == 0) {
    if ($num % 11 == 0) {
      if ($num % 10 == 0) {
        if ($num % 9 == 0) {
          if ($num % 8 == 0) {  
            if ($num % 7 == 0) {
              if ($num % 6 == 0) {
                if ($num % 5 == 0) {
                  if ($num % 4 == 0) {  
                    if ($num % 3 == 0) {
                      if ($num % 2 == 0) {
                        echo $num;
                        exit();
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: In case anyone is curious the answer is [`27,720`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=common+multiples+12%2C11%2C10%2C9%2C8%2C7%2C6%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C2).

Comment: Seems like you could make use of another for loop inside the current loop.  Make use of `break` if necessary.

Comment: of course the answer is 27720, but is there any other reliable way to get the same result.

Comment: Well, you don't need the 6, 5, 4, 3, or 2 case.  Those are already being handled.

Comment: And you don't need the check against 12 either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
$max = 12;
$num = $max;
while(true) {
    for($i = 2; $i <= $max; ++$i) {
        if ($num % $i !== 0) break;
    }
    if ($i > $max) break;
    $num += $max;
}

var_dump($num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
for ($i = 1, $num = 12; $i <= 999999; $i++, $num += 12) {
  if ($num % 11 || $num % 10 || $num % 9 || $num % 8 || $num % 7)
    continue;
  echo $num;
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 for ($i = 1; $i < 999999; $i++) {
     $num = 12 * $i;
     $divisible = true;
     for ($j = $num; $j > 1; $j --) {
         if ($num % $j !== 0) {
             $divisible = false;
             break;
         }
     }
     if ($divisible === true) {
        echo $num;
        break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a function + recursion to make it a little more flexible:

```
function foo($check, $max, $end) {
    if ($check%$max == 0 && $max >= $end){
            if ($max == $end) {
                    return $check;
            }
            return foo($check, $max-1, $end);
    }    
}

for ($i=1; $i<=999999;$i++) {
    $res = foo($i, 12, 2);
    if ($res) break;
}
echo $res;
?>
```